# How would I limit the results to a certain number and more?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm trying to limit the results only to those that placed 2 or more orders but I'm not sure what I did or what I need to do in order to get that result.

Here is what I've gotten so far:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID,
C.CompanyName,
OrdersPlaced = COUNT( O.OrderID),
TotalPrice = SUM( D.Quantity * D.UnitPrice)
FROM Customers AS C
INNER JOIN Orders AS O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] AS D ON O.OrderID = D.OrderID
WHERE O.OrderID >= 3
GROUP BY
O.OrderID,
C.CustomerID,
C.CompanyName;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
having count(distinct o.orderid) >= 2
```

I think the query you need is:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CompanyName,
       OrdersPlaced = COUNT( O.OrderID),
       TotalPrice = SUM( D.Quantity * D.UnitPrice)
FROM Customers C INNER JOIN
     Orders O 
     ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID INNER JOIN
     [Order Details] D
     ON O.OrderID = D.OrderID
WHERE O.OrderID >= 3
GROUP BY C.CustomerID, C.CompanyName;
```

You also need to remove the `OrderId` from the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I should put that after the Group by right? I do that and nothing returns and I know that there are values that should equal that.

Comment: Thank you removing the OrderId from the Group helped alot.